# How to remove all merged cells from an Excel file in php?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a Excel file like this:
[image]

I wrote a code that allows me to extract all the photos from the xlsx file and insert them in a folder.
There are several merged cells in the file and before processing I would like to remove all the merged cells from the Excel file. I tried with `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex("0")->unmergeCells();` but it doesn't work.

How can I solve my problem?

```
<?php

//uploaded xlsx file recovery
$xlsx="C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/xlsx_files/".date('Y_m_d H-i-s')."_file.xlsx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mon_fichier"]["tmp_name"],$xlsx);

require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xlsx);

//Unique name folder for the pictures
$dirname = uniqid();
mkdir("C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/pictures_folders/$dirname/");

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//Unmerge all cells
foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells) 
{ 
    $sheet->unmergeCells($cells);
    // var_dump($cells);
}
   
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
$objWriter->save('./unmerged_files/unmerged.xlsx');

//reading the xlsx file

foreach ($sheet->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing ) {

    
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                $extension = 'png'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                $extension = 'gif'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                $extension = 'jpg'; break;
        }
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';
        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
        $chemin = "C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/pictures_folders/$dirname/";
    
    }    
    
    //retrieving cell values for the images name
    $row = (int) substr($drawing->getCoordinates(), 1);  
    //Condition to read merged cell
    $stylecode = $sheet->getCell('H'.$row)->getValue();
    $colorcode = $sheet->getCell('E'.$row)->getValue();
    $finalname = $stylecode.'_'.$colorcode;
    $myFileName = $chemin.$finalname.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName, $imageContents); 
}
?>
```

Comment: You should upgrade. PHPExcel is outdated. Use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) instead.

Comment: Yes but it's still the same structure and the commands too, but I can't find how to do it in the documentation... @MarkusZeller

Comment: Consider using old software having bugs.

Comment: In the doc there is $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->unmergeCells('A18:E22'); to unmerge a selection of cells, but how to do it for a whole excel file when there are some cells merged and some not? @MarkusZeller

Comment: Never used that, but you could [detect](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Worksheet-Worksheet.html#method_unmergeCellsByColumnAndRow) them by `getMergeCells()` them and unmerge in a loop.

Comment: So I make a loop with `getMergeCells()` and all the merged ones I use `unmergeCells()`  to unmerge them?

Comment: That is the approach I would go.

Comment: I will try to look but I find it strange that there is not a function to do it directly on the whole xlsx file.

Comment: It's Open Source. You may contribute that function.

Comment: I tried with a loop but as soon as it passes over an unmerged cell it displays this error: `"Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Cell range A3:C3 not known as merged. in..."`

Comment: Why do you try to unmerge unmerged cells?

Comment: I made a loop to test all the cells of the file and unmerge them

Comment: `foreach(getMergeCells() as $cells) unmergeCells($cells);` should do it.

Comment: I don't have any errors during the execution but the cells are not unmerged in the final Excel file which modifies all the pictures...

Comment: Can you provide a download link to the Excel file?

Comment: You see my file @MarkusZeller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the library to [PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) because PHPExcel is outdated.

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$xlsx = './test/catalogmtnwr2021202009210323241.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($xlsx);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

Now I am testing what is merged and unmerge it

```
echo 'before unmerge: ', count($sheet->getMergeCells()), PHP_EOL;

foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells)
    $sheet->unmergeCells($cells);

echo 'after unmerge: ', count($sheet->getMergeCells()), PHP_EOL;
```

> before unmerge: 678
> after unmerge: 0

And at last write back into file

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('./test/unmerged.xlsx');
```

This unmerged the cells as expected

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can extend to the merge loop by getting the value before the unmerge, then unmerge and put the value back to all cells that have been unmerged.

Comment: So I keep my loop for unmerged all the cells you made and in 678 unmerged cells I add the old values?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would do it.

Comment: But then how do you tell him that this old value goes into this cell?

Comment: getMergeCells() gives you an array like `[A1:AA1, A2:AA2, A3:AA3, A7:A8]`. Create another loop inside for each range, setting that back to their cells via `$sheet->setCellValue();`.

Comment: I add  `foreach($sheet->getMergeCells() as $cells) $sheet->setCellValue($cells);` after the first foreach and before the creation of the new xlsx file?

Comment: No, inside the foreach another foreach.

Comment: Start reading about [rangeToArray()](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/)

Comment: I updated my code to see if this is what you want to do with both foreach?

Comment: Please do not change the question, because it is already answered. Create a new question instead.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've put it back the way it was before. Would you prefer I ask another question for this problem of filling in all the blanks after unmerged?